# Add html text formatting to titles

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml, html

I'm trying to add text formatting to a Title on my checkout page.

For example the shipping method Title is:

STANDARD SHIPPING RATE (free over $100)

I would like it to display with the '(free over $100)' to appear as smaller font size.

The checkout is a custom extension but the title gets called through this code:

`<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCarrierName($code)) ?>`

I've tried 'Standard Shipping Rate free over $100'
I'm not experienced at all with php but I'm assuming the escapeHtml function is removing all the html but is there a way to modify the code so that it does.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is a custom extension then just chnage this line to

`<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCarrierName($code)) ?>`

with below line

`<?php echo $this->getCarrierName($code) ?>`

this will not remove html tags

Comment: Hi @Murtuza Zabuawala, The above solution worked. I do however have a similar situation but the code is slightly different and I can't work it out. So far my code looks like this: `<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingDescription()) ?>` and I've tried multiple ways to get rid of the escapehtml but I've been unsuccesful. My Shipping description is `Standard Shipping Rate<small> - free over $100</small>` and I need it to display without the html tags. Cheers

Comment: you can use  php `str_replace` function in that case